# 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' on Laravel 5

Tags: php, debugging, laravel-5, csrf

I am getting a lot of these errors :

```
[2015-06-25 18:27:00] production.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in /home/xxx/public_html/vendor/compiled.php:2550
Stack trace:
#0 /home/xxx/public_html/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(17): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#1 /home/xxx/public_html/vendor/compiled.php(9197): App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#2 /home/xxx/public_html/vendor/compiled.php(12377): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 /home/xxx/public_html/vendor/compiled.php(9197): Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#4 /home/xxx/public_html/vendor/compiled.php(11067): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /home/xxx/public_html/vendor/compiled.php(9197): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#6 /home/xxx/public_html/vendor/compiled.php(12079): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 /home/xxx/public_html/vendor/compiled.php(9197): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#8 /home/xxx/public_html/vendor/compiled.php(12027): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 /home/xxx/public_html/vendor/compiled.php(9197): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#10 /home/xxx/public_html/vendor/compiled.php(2589): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /home/xxx/public_html/vendor/compiled.php(9197): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#12 /home/xxx/public_html/vendor/platform/installer/src/Middleware/Installer.php(57): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 /home/xxx/public_html/vendor/compiled.php(9197): Platform\Installer\Middleware\Installer->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#14 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 /home/xxx/public_html/vendor/compiled.php(9188): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 /home/xxx/public_html/vendor/compiled.php(1996): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#17 /home/xxx/public_html/vendor/compiled.php(1983): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /home/xxx/public_html/public/index.php(68): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 {main}
```

I don't manage to find where they are coming from exactly as the site has a lot of traffic.

I have this at the top of every page :

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

All my forms have this :

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

I'd rather not remove CSRF like people advise on other posts.

Do you have any idea how I can debug this to find out where the error is originating ? Just looking for the debug idea that will help find the error.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you requesting your form data via ajax? And are your sessions work properly?

Comment: Please answer @DavidDomain question, Also include the code for your forms

Comment: Hello, yes the sessions work properly and I don't use AJAX. Do you think it could be that APIs are making POST requests to my site without the CSRF ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the exception and flash the user like so:

```
    if ($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
        return response()->redirect('login')->with('status', 'Token expired, please try again.');
    }
```

Put this in `App\Exceptions\Handler::render()`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it seems like these errors where originating from POST request made by the outside world to my site. For now I have disabled CSRF but plan on implementing a solution like this :
http://www.camroncade.com/disable-csrf-for-specific-routes-laravel-5/

Comment: Disabling CSRF is a terrible idea. Please see my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Just run these commands

```
php artisan clear-compiled
composer dump-autoload
```